# How to detect amount of tabs for my domain?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect how many tabs of my site are opened in current browser?
The problem is to restrict multiple manipulations of data to be synchonized.

I've only found how to detect for current tab: is hidden or not:

```
(function() {
  var hidden = "hidden";

  // Standards:
  if (hidden in document)
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "mozHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "webkitHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "msHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onchange);
  // IE 9 and lower:
  else if ("onfocusin" in document)
    document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange;
  // All others:
  else
    window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide
    = window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

  function onchange (evt) {
    var v = "visible", h = "hidden",
        evtMap = {
          focus:v, focusin:v, pageshow:v, blur:h, focusout:h, pagehide:h
        };

    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.type in evtMap)
      document.body.className = evtMap[evt.type];
    else
      document.body.className = this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible";
  //console.log(this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible");
  }

  // set the initial state (but only if browser supports the Page Visibility API)
  if( document[hidden] !== undefined )
    onchange({type: document[hidden] ? "blur" : "focus"});
})();
```

But what about total user workflow? Is there any lib what can help to detect, how many tabs are close and define "the major tab" for them?

**COMMENT**

A user can edit a database inside a web browser.
In order to prevent async behaviour for different tabs I want to forbid to edit the database in different tabs.
i.e.,
1. I want to define 'the major tab' there user manipulates the database.
2. If a user opens a new tabs, the site says:"I've been opened my site in another tab, please, close current tab, etc."

Comment: What does "The problem is to restrict multiple manipulations of data to be synchonized." mean?

Comment: `detect how many tabs are close` - all of them. `define "the major tab" for them` - by whose reckoning? yours or theirs?

Comment: @JaromandaX , edited

Comment: Wrong approach. Check if data is changed and provide an option to overwrite instead.

Comment: @PeeHaa why wrong? I'm just want to decrease cpu server usage.

Comment: You are decreasing what now? How does that relate to you question?

Comment: I do not want to sync every user modified data. I want to send changes by 'blocks of 10-20 changes'. What's why, I want to detect, is there any tab is opened to prevent async. Anyway, if this is not common pipeline for synchronization, I will do as you said: sync every step.

Comment: There is not really a sane way to check how many tabs are open. What happens in the user's user agent is not made available to you. I could think of a way using long polling / ws to detect it, but the cure is worse than the disease

Comment: `There is not really a sane way to check how many tabs are open` - you don't really need to know how many are open if you are trying to limit to 1. Every time you open the page in a new tab, you check if it's already open in another tab ... hopefully you'll only ever have one already open, and the new one trying to open, so the count is irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cut down version of something I had to implement on a site, against my better judgement, because the backend code was poorly designed. So, until we fix the backend, we've put in a function like this to avoid issues where creating new records of the same type in two different tabs could cross polute the data in bizarre ways.

```
var pageInterlock = (function () {
    var store = window.localStorage,
        storeKey = false, // we actually have logic to set this to specific values depending on which page the user is on. it remains false to indicate no locking required
        unlock = function () {
            try {
                store.removeItem(storeKey);
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
            return true;
        },
        lock = function () {
            store.setItem(storeKey, JSON.stringify({ locked: new Date() }));
            window.addEventListener('unload', unlock);
            return true;
        },
        tryLock = function () {
            var lck = store.getItem(storeKey);
            if (lck === null) {
                return lock();
            }
            return JSON.parse(lck);
        },
        init = function () {
            var lockedOnDate,
                lockData;
            if (storeKey) { //you can put conditions here, for example in our system, we only prevent multiple tabs in "create" mode
                lockData = tryLock();
                if (lockData !== true) { // lock exists
                    lockedOnDate = new Date(lockData.locked);
                    lockedOnDate.setMinutes(lockedOnDate.getMinutes() + 1); // first minute will never be considered stale
                    if (+lockedOnDate > Date.now()) { // using the above lockedOnDate, you can force close if, say, the other page got the lock less than 1 minute ago, otherwise do a conditional close
                        // forcibly close the window if you can, or redirect to a safe page
                    }
                    else {
                        // in case there's a stale lock, prompt the user, close/redirect the window if the user chooses appropriately
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    return {
        init: init // this gets called on page loaded event
    };
} ());
window.addEventListener('load', pageInterlock.init); // initialise the interlock
```

Please note that this uses `window.localStorage`, so, IE8 or later only

You possibly could do this with cookies, I'm not sure really, never even considered them

Comment: thanks. Nice solution. But what happens when browser crashes? Is it better to use sessionStorage instead of localStorage?

Comment: that's what the "stale" locks stuff handles ... we pop up a message saying "proceed if you're sure you aren't doing this in another tab" - then give the user a choice - not ideal, but our pages don't crash browsers :p

Comment: Session storage isn't an option `Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated` - though, cookies may be better in that case, I just haven't bothered with cookies

Comment: thanks. I've just tested - you are right. sessionStorage doesn't help in this case.

Comment: As I said in the answer, I implemented this against my better judgement. In our case at least, we had to do it because of sloppy back-end coding, by people who have left the company, since they left, we've been slowly re-writing the backend so that we wont need this sort of kludge ... By the way, I'm not saying your backend code is at all wrong, just in our case we found a cleaner solution that does allow multiple tabs on the same operation